# How can I implement ACL into my Vue project using vue-browser-acl?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router, acl

Using this [ACL library for Vue](https://github.com/mblarsen/vue-browser-acl#setup) I have been trying to implement ACLs into [my Vue-based project](https://github.com/rajsinghUSA/testlogin/blob/master/src/main.js#L13) using the following code in 2 files:

**main.js**

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import Acl from "vue-browser-acl";

const user = { name: "Raj", role: "normal" };

Vue.use(Acl, user, acl => {
  acl.rule("normal", "pages", user => user.role == "normal");
});

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

**pages/PageStats.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 v-role:normal>This is the stats page authenticated</h1>
    <h1>This is the stats page unauthenticated</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

However, even with the user having `role: "normal"`, I can't see the `<h1 v-role:normal>` tag. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for that library is quite confusing but I think in order to use the `v-role` directive, you need to [configure a global rule](https://github.com/mblarsen/browser-acl#additional-parameters-and-global-rules).

```js
// remove the "pages" subject
acl.rule("normal", ({ role }) => role === "normal");
```

Demo ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-lake-p1ndn

---

In order to use string subjects, there appears to be some string casing rules you must follow. Either use Pascal-cased names like `"Pages"` or configure ACL to use plain case mode

```js
Vue.use(Acl, user, acl => {
  acl.rule("normal", ({ role }) => role === "normal");
  acl.rule("view", "pages");
}, {
  caseMode: false //  configure plain case mode
});
```

```html
<div v-role:normal>Normal role can view</div>
<div v-can:view="'pages'">Can view pages</div>
```

See https://github.com/mblarsen/vue-browser-acl#casemode

Comment: thank you, that definitely worked. However, what if I want to use a subject such as "pages" or "post", how would that work?

Comment: @Raj you can't use `v-role` for that. You'd need to use `v-can`, eg `v-can:view="'pages'"`

Comment: that's fine but when I tried using `v-can` using my original question's example, it still didn't work.

Comment: @Raj I found what your problem was and updated my answer

Comment: I still don't fully understand how I should be using the so-called `subjects`, as in how to use Page or "page" or "Page" or "pages" or "Pages", but overall you did answer my original question which has had me stuck for **days**. Thank you!

Comment: @Raj no problem. I _think_ that where they have `Page` in the doco, it's a class. You can see some of it here ~ https://github.com/mblarsen/browser-acl#subject-mapping. I too am not clear in its usage though. Good luck with your project